# Select request to select 5 tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 5 tables being those:

`my_books` table:

- id_book
- title
- price
- description

`genre` table:

- id_genre
- genre(genre description in this column)

`genre_ind` table:

- id_book
- id_genre(table combines genre and books tables)

`authors` table:

- id_author
- author(author name in this column)

`author_ind` table:

- id_book
- id_author

I need to join tables to select all books info by genre id. Since author info stored on other table I need to add authors info according to book id.

Trying to do that in a single query and so far I have the following query:

```
   SELECT my_books.id_book, 
          my_books.title, 
          my_books.price, 
          my_books.descrip, 
          a.genre, 
          s.authors 
     FROM my_books
LEFT JOIN genre_ind 
       ON my_books.id_book = genre_ind.id_book
LEFT JOIN genre a 
       ON genre_ind.id_genre = a.id_genre
LEFT JOIN author_ind 
       ON books.id_book=author_ind.id_book
LEFT JOIN authors s 
       ON author_ind.id_author=s.id_author
    WHERE author_ind.id_book=my_books.id_book 
      AND genre_ind.id_genre=%d
```

I have functional query if I need to select info from my_books info based on the genre id but then I try to extend it to select author info and it does not work!

Update:

now code quire looks like this:

```
    SELECT my_books.id_book,
           my_books.title, 
           my_books.price, 
           my_books.descrip,
           a.genre,
           s.authors
      FROM my_books
 LEFT JOIN genre_ind
        ON my_books.id_book = genre_ind.id_book
 LEFT JOIN genre a 
        ON genre_ind.id_genre = a.id_genre
 LEFT JOIN author_ind 
        ON my_books.id_book = author_ind.id_book
 LEFT JOIN authors s 
        ON author_ind.id_author = s.id_author
     WHERE genre_ind.id_genre=%d
```

and the error I get is: MySQL: #1054 - Unknown column 's.authors' in 'field list'

Thank you for your help, really appreciate it

Ok, problem solved. Thank you so much for your time and help!!!!

correct quire:

```
SELECT my_books.id_book,
           my_books.title, 
           my_books.price, 
           my_books.descrip,
           a.genre,
           s.author
      FROM my_books
 LEFT JOIN genre_ind
        ON my_books.id_book = genre_ind.id_book
 LEFT JOIN genre a 
        ON genre_ind.id_genre = a.id_genre
 LEFT JOIN author_ind 
        ON my_books.id_book = author_ind.id_book
 LEFT JOIN authors s 
        ON author_ind.id_author = s.id_author
     WHERE genre_ind.id_genre=%d
```

Comment: how it's not working? can you give few more details about an error?

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: can you try to remove where clause and check if its working?

Comment: @metamorph_online post the relevant part of code as well as the error mentioned is not one coming from wrong query.

Comment: hm, if where statement will be removed what the condition will be used by mysql since id_genre is defined there

Comment: @Prix, actually it is query problem. php is 100% functional as I've mentioned, I have working query that works with php.


SELECT my_books.title, my_books.author, my_books.price, my_books.descrip, genre.genre FROM my_books
         LEFT JOIN genre_ind ON my_books.id_book = genre_ind.id_book
      LEFT JOIN genre genre ON genre_ind.id_genre = genre.id_genre
         WHERE genre_ind.id_genre=%d 
         ORDER BY my_books.title"

Comment: @metamorph_online post how your code is at the moment with the query that fails and I am sure some one will promptly spot the problem.

Comment: Oh how we love "it doesn't work" as an explanation of a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is this `on` clause:

```
ON books.id_book=author_ind.id_book
```

Nothing called `books` has been defined.

A second problem is that the `where` clause is undoing the effect of the `left outer join`.

Perhaps you mean this:

```
 FROM my_books LEFT JOIN
      genre_ind 
      ON my_books.id_book = genre_ind.id_book LEFT JOIN
      genre a 
      ON genre_ind.id_genre = a.id_genre LEFT JOIN
      author_ind 
      ON my_books.id_book = author_ind.id_book LEFT JOIN
---------^ changed from `books`
      authors s
      ON author_ind.id_author=s.id_author
WHERE genre_ind.id_genre=%d
```

Comment: ops, I did miss the books.id_book:) thanks, changed to my_book.id_book
error is still there. Can you please specify if I change the WHERE statement how to tell the quire to select authors id in the author_ind compare to id_books?

Comment: I get the following error after update:
#1054 - Unknown column 's.authors' in 'field list'

Comment: @metamorph_online: Your column name is `author` but you are using `authors`. Correct it

Comment: @G one God damn it, Gump! You're a god damn genius!(C) Thank you:))))